# VSCode bad javascript formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am editing some javascript files (particularly, reactjs coed) in VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04. However, the "formatting" is really terrible.

Before:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} />
            </div>
        );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = "App" >
            <
            Dropzone onDrop = {
                this.onDrop
            }
            /> <
            /div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Previously, I was editing these files on Windows 10 in VS Code, and the formatter was great. Is there an extension I am missing? Or what am I doing wrong here. To format, I am using the "Format Document" keyboard shortcut.

Here are my current extensions:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I personally use [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) for JS and CSS formatting, and [JS JSX Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=skyran.js-jsx-snippets) for JSX in React. I have tried a lot of others, but with those 2 I can assure you your React code will look beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

The culprit for this behavior was Beatify extension on Vscode in my case. Disabling resolved the [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/440).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution,

1. change the language manually to "javaScript React"

[image]

2. try with your favorite formatter(you can install vs code extensions such as "Prettier","beautify")

Cheers !