# I am facing difficulty in writing html commands in JSX . The code editor is vs code. The tags are getting dis aligned automatically

Tags: reactjs, web, web-development-server

The tags are getting aligned improperly on their own while I am adding HTML tags in the JSX. I am new to react js.
[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TBaw.png)

Comment: What is the file name?

Comment: app.js is the file name

Comment: It is mostly the editor issue. Can you update your VSCode and restart it? Also, try to disable auto formatting by the VSCode if updating and restarting does not help. Also, try renaming the file to "app.jsx". See [VSCode bad javascript formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53608686/2873538)